# Noob SCI-FI Sound Designer...

Tags: noob, sound-design, selling, scifi

Hey There! This is my first post here so, please forgive me if I am asking obvious questions or just stating the obvious. ;)
I am a 20 year veteran of the Television industry as an Editor (Avid) and a musician/remixer in my free-time, (I am also a father of twin boys and have a 6 month old daughter,) so really, I have no free time. Ha Ha

That said, for the last year or so, I have been creating, building and refining an ongoing library of Science Fiction themed sound effects that I would like to release at some point in the future and make mountains of money doing it. Easy, right?
In all seriousness, does anyone here have any words of advice, encouragement or just an idea on where I should start?
I have seem some big company aggregate websites that basically do the leg-work & sell for you, but then take a cut of the licensing to independent groups just doing it all themselves. 
As simple & attractive as "doing it all yourself" sounds, I can only imagine how tough that could be. How do you target your niche end user when you don't have an "in" the way larger Distribution companies do?

If there are any resources that could help me get started, I'd appreciate any insight anyone might give.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea what Human said is pretty much on, you can even look at things like zencart or those competitors for automatic digital goods distribution so while you sleep you can get paid and deliver. Then I would just go around to some of the sites like designing sound or forums and start announcing. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If the product is high quality, large enough in content and the price is less than what the bigger distributors ask, then I only see a marketing problem (i.e. letting people know that such library exists). You can set up a website/server for sharing it and Paypal/Google Payments/other for the payments. I think it's very easy to see how such marketing can be done (sound-related websites, blogs, forums, referrals from people who have their own websites with visitors).

In general, I would say that selling sound effects is not rocket science, unless it's done by the bigger distributors (more content, more worries).

The only substantial benefit in bigger distributors is that they have a somewhat established consumer base, which even get their email newsletters etc. But they also have loads of content, i.e. your library might be a needle in a haystack.

http://www.creativefieldrecording.com/2011/02/18/selling-sound-effects-how-to-choose-where-to-sell-part-1/ 
http://www.creativefieldrecording.com/2013/03/06/four-ways-to-sell-sound-effects-the-future/

Comment: Thanks much, Human... The links you provided are great! What you said makes sense.
I just need to get organized and start.
Thanks again!